# Child category list on the sidebar

Tags: wordpress

Good day can some one help me I need to get the sub categories associated with my post and put it on a widget as a list in the sidecar how can I do this? this is how it would look like example so Computers would be main category child/subcategory would be monitor , cpu etc.

Computers (main category)

```
Monitor
Processor
Harddrive
psu
Memory
```

Now if I have a post lets say I have an article "hp e241i review" on the sidebar I need to have a list of all the child/ sub category associated with my post, so it be Monitor, processor, HardDrive, Psu and memory. Is this possible Appreciate your help

*edit* here is what I used my issue with this is I need to get the main category id of the article place inside the "parent" array replacing "Category ID" just don't know how

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'orderby' => 'name',
'parent' =>  'Category ID',
'hide_empty' => 1 ,
 );
$categories = get_categories( $args );
$content='';
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '">' . $category->name . '</a>      <br/>';

}
?>
```

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I tried the code above

Answer (score 2):

to list all the categories including sub categories use `<?php echo get_the_category_list();?>`, This will print the categories and sub categories

Comment: Hi Abuzer I need to get the sub categories associated with the post that I have on my example I have a article title hp e241i review which is on the child category of computer which is monitor. On the sidebar I need to show the sub categories associated with is so it needs to display Monitor, cpu, hard drive etc. I would also have other main category like kitchen and sub category for it like pots & pans, oven etc.

Comment: have you tried `<?php echo get_the_category_list();?>` , it will print the main cat and sub cat

Comment: Yes it is only showing the child category which the article is assigned to for the example it's only showing "monitor", I need to show all child categories associated with the article monitor, cpu, etc.

Answer (score 0):

While adding post, create parent category "Computer" and create other categories but select parent category as "Computer" for child categories on right sidebar. IF you want to create more childs, be sure you select proper parent.

Comment: Thanks Raju I just need the child category associated with the article. I don't need to list all main categories